# Tagging specific parts of QTextDocument

Tags: pyqt5, semantic-markup, tagging, qtextedit, qtextdocument

I have to edit a document which has been tagged semantically.

Assume I have an HTML document where some or all paragraphs (or span) have been tagged with a specific class name, something like: `<p class="bio"><span class="name">John</span><span class="surname">Doe</span>is a <span class="job">carpenter</span> living in <span class="place">York</span>.</p><p class="story">He was working at his bench when...</p>`

I want to use a QTextEdit widget to edit such text (if possible).

Additional requirements are:

- Each `class` should have specific graphic rendering (this should be easy using CSS).
- Editing specific `<span>` should preserve `class` (i.e.: if I edit "John" -> "Jonathan" it should still have `class="name"`).
- I should be able to apply `class` to specific pieces of text (i.e.: select some text, open a context menu and select one of the possible `class`es).
- Remove tagging from selection.
- Serialize edited text (i.e.: walk the edited text, recognize `class` changes and be able to produce whatever markup I want).
- Note `class`es can be contained one inside another (but not overlap partially); this means some piece of code has two (or more) `class`es.

Can this be achieved with standard means?

As far as I have seen QTextDocument and associated classes (e.g.: QTextFrame, QTextFormat, etc.) are geared toward visual representation (font style, color etc.) while I need some "logic" tagging that may or may not reflect in visual changes. I mean: text can be all in the same font/color/background, but moving cursor over it I should be able to list all `class`es active in that specific place (if any).

I am coding in PyQt5, if this is relevant.

The only (rather ugly!) way I seem to see to achieve this is to use `QTextCharFormat`'s `tooltip` property to store class(es) of each `QTextFragment`. Is there a better option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone having the same problem:

QTextCharFormat has a property (named "Property") which can be used to hold arbitrary data.

You need to:

- define your set of codes (higher than `QtGui.QTextFormat.UserProperty` to avoid clash with existing properties).
- set with: `format.setProperty(mycode, myvalue)`
- read back with: `value = format.property(mycode)`

Other Widgets have similar (but NOT identical!) mechanisms (e.g.: QStandardItem has a similar property called `data`)

IMPORTANT NOTE: if you are using PyQt there are severe restrictions in what you can store and safely retrieve (storing a `QTextDocument` in a `QStandardItem.setData(doc, mycode)` will *not* work reliably because only the reference will be stored and if the underlying python object is garbage collected you'll have a nice crash (SIGSEGV).